# magento email sending programmatically

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, reset-password

I am trying to use following code to send recovery email.
But it never send email? any suggestion?
I am using 1.9 version magento.

```
if ($customer->getId()) 
{
    try
    {
        $newResetPasswordLinkToken =  Mage::helper('customer')->generateResetPasswordLinkToken();
        $customer->changeResetPasswordLinkToken($newResetPasswordLinkToken);
        $customer->save();
        $customer->sendPasswordResetConfirmationEmail();
    }
    catch (Exception $exception) 
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have [cron jobs enabled and configured](https://amasty.com/blog/configure-magento-cron-job/#Magento_1x)?  If so, run `SELECT * FROM core_email_queue;` and see if your email is being added to the queue.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I have installed mail server and cron. After that, it works successfully. But now i have encountered new situation that sent order emails are not cleared from the core_email_queue. Certainly several days passed after mails being processed, but not deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have installed Postfix mail server. And I have added following line with crontab -e
* * * * * sh /var/www/html/cron.sh 
Then it works fine.